# Обособлять одиночное деепричастие или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

*Пирог(,) не размораживая(,) разогревать в микроволновой печи.*

Вроде бы очевидно наречное значение: не размораживая = без разморозки, но при этом сочетание без запятых "не размораживая разогревать" кажется мне нелогичным, ведь нельзя разогреть и при этом не разморозить. Можно оставить запятые? Или без них все нормально?

Answer (score 4):

Я не соглашусь с вашим выбором наречного значения. Здесь разморозка является отдельным от разогревания шагом в рецепте (конкретно в этом рецепте это шаг, который необходимо пропустить). И деепричастие имеет ярко выраженный глагольный оттенок. Действия которые вам нужно выполнить с пирогом: `не размораживать` и `разогревать`. Фразу можно переписать так, сделав из деепричастного оборота однородное сказуемое:

*Пирог не размораживать, а разогревать в микроволновой печи.*

Соответственно, действует следующее правило из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> § 70. Одиночные деепричастия обособляются при сохранении ими глагольного значения — обозначении действия.

Поэтому и обособляем: *Пирог, не размораживая, разогревать в микроволновой печи.*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: А если так: Пирог разогревать в микроволновой печи не размораживая?